Is there a way to simplify/correct this mesh?
I imported these slats as .OBJ files from a Rhino model. They are primarily simple rectangles with some having mitered ends. They have what appear to be extra vertices near the ends. When I apply the shade smooth operation or modifier it deforms the slats based on these additional vertices. Is there a way to simplify/rebuild the geometry without needing to recreate it? I have hundreds of slats and would like to do the operation in bulk. I am noticing that all geometry I imported from the Rhino model has this issue. 

Are you sure the geometry is actually changing? See this documentation on what Shade Smooth & Flat do.

Select all with A, then X > Limited Dissolve, and perhaps adjust the angle in the tool options at the bottom left. Although the default is 5°, if most angles there are 90° or at least a lot more than 5°, this should not be necessary.

Oh, and I forgot to say, maybe there are vertex duplicates and so on, after selecting all and before you use the Limited Dissolve, you can probably try M > Merge > By Distance.

@TheLabCat The geometry is not changing. Thank you for the clarification.
